# COPY csv file with additionnal datas

Tags: postgresql, csv, libpqxx, postgresql-copy

I have the following table :

```
persons(id,id_tech,name,nationality,id_list)
```

And a CSV file containing the datas for the column id_tech, name, and nationality.

Importing the data like so is working :

```
\copy persons(id_tech,name,nationality) FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

The `id_list` value is not in the CSV file because the file has to be imported on many servers where the value of this id can be different.

Is there a way to import the CSV file while providing an additional value for a specific column? I can't find anything relevant on the documentation.

Edit 1--
Note that all my command will be perform with `pqxx` in C++ (multi platform). I'm trying to avoid editing the file because of it's size.

Edit 2 --
I'm considering the following approach:

- Create a temp table with a correct default value for the field I need
- Import File into this temp table
- Copy temp table to final table
- Remove temp table

But I'm unsure of the performance. Biggest import can be close to a 500K lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution which seems more than ok.

As stated in my OP , i use libpqxx to insert data , so instead of running a COPY sql request directly , i simply use [pqxx::stream_to](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.3/a01478.html)

Which allow me to add addtional field if needed :

```
pqxx::stream_to stream(w, mTable, std::vector<std::string>{"id_tech","name","nationality","extra_col"});
csv::CSVReader reader(filePath);
for (csv::CSVRow& row : reader) {

    stream << std::make_tuple(row[0].get<long long>(), row[1].get<std::string>(), row[2].get<std::string>(), custom_id);
}
stream.complete();
```

Taking around 10s to import 300K lines which is fine for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you could use for example awk to add the additional value field to your data and use `psql` to read from from stdin:

```
$ cat copy.sql
\copy persons(id_tech,name,nationality,extra_col) FROM '/dev/stdin' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

and then:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    print $1,$2,$3,"additional value"
}' file.csv | psql -h host -d database -f file.sql
```

(tested on PostgreSQL 12.4)

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i'n interacting with postgres in c++ not only under Linux. I could modifiy the file in C++ but due to their size i 'd like to avoid that

Comment: If you can't read from stdin and need to read from a file, I guess you just have to edit the file before loading or load to a staging table first. Good luck.